# Alternating Array Elements

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this method below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (button[i].BackColor == Color.GreenYellow) // if button colour is GreenYellow              
      {
         button[i].BackColor = Color.Beige;       // change to beige     
         break;
      }

    else if (button[i].BackColor == Color.Beige)  // if button is already beige
      {
         button[i + 1].BackColor = Color.Beige;   //skip current button and change next button to beige
         break;
      }
}
```

The method works, but not in the way I intend it to work. In the `else if` section of the code, what I want is that if the button colour is already `Beige`, skip the current button and colour in the next button.

The problem is that it only works for the first 2 buttons, then fails to do so for the next 8 buttons. Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10)
{
    if (button[i].BackColor == Color.GreenYellow) // if button colour is GreenYellow              
    {
        button[i].BackColor = Color.Beige;       // change to beige     
        i++;
    }   
    else if (button[i].BackColor == Color.Beige)  // if button is already beige
    {
        button[i + 1].BackColor = Color.Beige;   //skip current button and change next button to beige
        i+=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you increment `i` by three in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Break`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (button[i].BackColor == Color.GreenYellow) // if button colour is GreenYellow              
      {
         button[i].BackColor = Color.Beige;       // change to beige     

      }

      else if (button[i].BackColor == Color.Beige)  // if button is already beige
      {
         button[i + 1].BackColor = Color.Beige;   //skip current button and change next button to beige
         i += 1;

      }
}
```

Comment: This will have a domino effect. If you hit beige, all to the end will become beige. Not sure if the OP wants that.

Comment: Here you increment `i` by three in the loop when you hit a beige item.

Comment: @Servy My mistake. I basically asked him to do so :)

Comment: @Ramshad the `break;` is essential or else the buttons will keep colouring in the buttons beige until all is coloured

Answer (score 0):

Unsure by your question if you want ALL buttons to behave this way or just those in an array between 1 and 10. If it's the former, you can use:

```
    var buttons = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Where(b => b.GetType() == typeof(Button) && b.BackColor != Color.Beige)
        .ToList();

    buttons.ForEach(b => b.BackColor = Color.Beige);
```

Otherwise, you will want to stick to the method Peter posted.